# Create session without a user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to create session without a user. (Native application)

To [get an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) is fine.
But I cannot [create session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0#api-call-to-get-a-session).

**Code:**

```cs
using var client = new HttpClient();
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/8C353AA80F001A1F!350000/workbook/createSession");
request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
request.Content = new StringContent("{ \"persistChanges\": true }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

**Errror:**

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, ... }
```

Could you tell me idea of how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application-only permissions are currently not supported.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workbook-createsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

[image: List of permissions]

Feel free to file a uservoice request here https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests